# why this method cannot work for me, to create one-dimensional array?

Tags: java, methods

i'm beginner in java, i want to use the Scanner class to create a method, that can i use it in another method:

```
package my_train_1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Use_methods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("voila les nouvelles chaines de caractéres que vous vennez de saisir");
        saisir(sclavier);

    } 

    public static void saisir(String sclavier[]) {
        int p=0;
        while(p<5) {
            System.out.print("saisir une chaine de caracter");
            Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
            sclavier[p]=reader.nextLine();
            p++;
        }

    }

}
```

so, what i can do to compile it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `saisir(sclavier);`, `sclavier` is nothing, you have to provide a new array to the method `saisir(new String[5]);`

---

If you need to use it back after, save it in a variable :

```
String[] res = new String[5];
saisir(res);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

---

Also, use only one `Scanner`, not a new one each time, no need to

```
public static void saisir(String sclavier[]) {
    int p = 0;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (p < 5) {
        System.out.print("saisir une chaine de caracter");
        sclavier[p] = reader.nextLine();
        p++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package my_train_1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Use_methods {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("voila les nouvelles chaines de caractéres que vous vennez de saisir");
    int p=0;
    String[] sclavier = new String[5];
    Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
    while(p<5) {
        System.out.print("saisir une chaine de caracter");            
        sclavier[p]=reader.nextLine();
        p++;
    }

}
```